# How do I make a message get sent to every device on a WiFi network?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I’m trying to build an application and I don’t know how to make a message pop up on every device connected to a private WiFi network if you are connected to this network? Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: A popup in what software program? This is a pretty vague question...

Comment: That would be a function of the router.

Answer (score 2):

## You cannot.

How would that even work. The TV, the iSomething, the Android phones and Windows PCs, the oven and coffee maker, Alexa and that smart button would *all* need a common protocol. They don't have one. It's not that simple. We wish it were, but sadly, doing computer stuff is still work :)